# How to display image side by side?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do place 2 image side by side and then have another line with 2 images side by side?
Sorry for asking

```
<div class="container">
<audio id="a" src="../Media/Sound/a.mp3"></audio>
<img class="static" src="../Media/Static_Characters/a.png" alt="No Image">
<img class="active" src="../Media/Gifs/a.gif" alt="No Image">
<p class="center">a</p>

<audio id="a" src="../Media/Sound/a.mp3"></audio>
<img class="static" src="../Media/Static_Characters/a.png" alt="No Image">
<img class="active" src="../Media/Gifs/a.gif" alt="No Image">
<p class="center">a</p>

<audio id="a" src="../Media/Sound/a.mp3"></audio>
<img class="static" src="../Media/Static_Characters/a.png" alt="No Image">
<img class="active" src="../Media/Gifs/a.gif" alt="No Image">
<p class="center">a</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display-block` in your image and set `vertical-align` to `top` in your image

**CSS**

```
img {display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;}
```

**HTML**

Also there is no closing in your audio tag. I've re edited it for you.

```
<div class="container">
<audio id="a" src="../Media/Sound/a.mp3"></audio>
<img class="static" src="../Media/Static_Characters/a.png" alt="No Image">
<img class="active" src="../Media/Gifs/a.gif" alt="No Image"/>
<p class="center">a</p>

<audio id="a" src="../Media/Sound/a.mp3"></audio>
<img class="static" src="../Media/Static_Characters/a.png" alt="No Image">
<img class="active" src="../Media/Gifs/a.gif" alt="No Image">
<p class="center">a</p>

<audio id="a" src="../Media/Sound/a.mp3"></audio>
<img class="static" src="../Media/Static_Characters/a.png" alt="No Image">
<img class="active" src="../Media/Gifs/a.gif" alt="No Image">
<p class="center">a</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way. Just use flexbox on the container.

All I did was add the below CSS to your container class and limited the number of images per container to 3.

```
.container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
}
```

Using [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) will also maintain a responsive layout on desktop and mobile.

Run the snippet below:

```css
.container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
}

/*image styles for example only, all you need is the container CSS*/

img {
width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<audio id="a" src="../Media/Sound/a.mp3"></audio
<img class="static" src="../Media/Static_Characters/a.png" alt="No Image">
<img class="active" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/11/18/08/21/bonsai-4634225_960_720.jpg" alt="No Image">
<p class="center">a</p>

<audio id="a" src="../Media/Sound/a.mp3"></audio
<img class="static" src="../Media/Static_Characters/a.png" alt="No Image">
<img class="active" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/11/18/08/21/bonsai-4634225_960_720.jpg" alt="No Image">
<p class="center">a</p>

<audio id="a" src="../Media/Sound/a.mp3"></audio
<img class="static" src="../Media/Static_Characters/a.png" alt="No Image">
<img class="active" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/11/18/08/21/bonsai-4634225_960_720.jpg" alt="No Image">
<p class="center">a</p>       
</div>          

<div class="container">
<audio id="a" src="../Media/Sound/a.mp3"></audio
<img class="static" src="../Media/Static_Characters/a.png" alt="No Image">
<img class="active" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/11/18/08/21/bonsai-4634225_960_720.jpg" alt="No Image">
<p class="center">a</p>

<audio id="a" src="../Media/Sound/a.mp3"></audio
<img class="static" src="../Media/Static_Characters/a.png" alt="No Image">
<img class="active" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/11/18/08/21/bonsai-4634225_960_720.jpg" alt="No Image">
<p class="center">a</p>

<audio id="a" src="../Media/Sound/a.mp3"></audio
<img class="static" src="../Media/Static_Characters/a.png" alt="No Image">
<img class="active" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/11/18/08/21/bonsai-4634225_960_720.jpg" alt="No Image">
<p class="center">a</p>       
</div>
```