# Display elements side by side html/css

Tags: html, css

I added my html code and then my css code below, when in browser these pictures show up exactly on top of each other inside of having two of the same pictures side by side? i put display inline block but they still show up on top and cannot figure out to get them to move

```
<div class="container">
        <img src="mole-head.png" alt="mole head" id="img1">
        <img src="mole-hill.png" alt="mole hill" id="img2">
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <img src="mole-head.png" alt="mole head" id="img1">
          <img src="mole-hill.png" alt="mole hill" id="img2">
          </div>


.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 640;
    height: 482;
    display: inline-block;
}

#img1 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 356px;
    width: 376px;
    left: 109px;
}

#img2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 220px;
    width: 640px;
    top: 262px;
```

Comment: You have duplicated id's - each image needs a unique id

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display image side by side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65015077/how-to-display-image-side-by-side)

Answer (score 0):

I found your problem, looks like you forgot something in your css. You forgot to add units on class `.container`

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="mole-head.png" alt="mole head" id="img1" />
  <img src="mole-hill.png" alt="mole hill" id="img2" />
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="mole-head.png" alt="mole head" id="img1" />
  <img src="mole-hill.png" alt="mole hill" id="img2" />
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 640px;
  height: 482px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#img1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 356px;
  width: 376px;
  left: 109px;
}

#img2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 220px;
  width: 640px;
  top: 262px;
}
```

Comment: my goodness, who would have thought units would make that much of a difference, how dumb am i, thank you so much